# Return Json from Controller to alert in View

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I went through many links but I think I found my problem is quite different. Json is returned from Controller but it is alerted as well as message is shown in blank window.I want only to alert it.

My AJAX :

```
<script>
    function confirm() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Form/tabledata',
            type: 'POST',

            data: $('#postForm').serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);

            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert(data);
              //  location.reload(true);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

My Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult tabledata(IEnumerable<tabledata> data)
    {
        try
        {
            DataColumn[] dtcs = new DataColumn[5] {
            new DataColumn("menu_item_id", typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("menu_item_name", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("menu_rate", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("qty", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("total", typeof(string))
            };
            var dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.AddRange(dtcs);
            foreach (tabledata td in data)
            {
                object[] row = { td.menu_item_id, td.menu_item_name, td.rate, td.qty, td.total };
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            return Json("successful.");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return Json("Unsuccessful.",JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Once it is alerted and after I click 'OK' I get  **'successful'**  in blank window.

Comment: From the code you show, there's nothing that would go to a blank page. There must be more.

Comment: Probably you're not returning the view somewhere. A JSON request should give alert box on the same page, not another blank one.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto sir I want to show alert on same page. I have nothing on the View.Just dummy table rows whose values are posted to the controller and Json should be shown as an alert.

Comment: Hi Niroj not sure what you wanted

Comment: Also share your View Code

Comment: @Dilip sir I just wanted to alert the json from Controller.Now I am getting alert as well as same message in a blank page.Thats all what I meant

Comment: Send me your view code from where you called this method confirm()

Comment: @Dilip sir below solution worked for me.That was my problem.Thank you also .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add `event.preventDefault();` before making ajax call because I think the button/control on whose click you are making this function call also submits the form.

Comment: Thank you sir.Same was the issue.